# How do I find spaces in strings with batch

Tags: batch-file

I've looked everywhere for an answer to this. Basically I need to find a " "(a space) in batch.

So, what i'm doing is making a custom command import/export batch script. Here is what i start by doing:

```
echo Enter commands file name without the .bat 
set/p "file=>"
```

Now, after that set/p... line, I want to test if the "file" string contains a space.

How I can achieve this without using a different coding language? I'm keeping this strictly batch.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'm not going to write your code for you, but if you actually _have_ "looked everywhere," and not found anything, I'll point you towards the `find` command and remind you that you can use the output of one command as the input of a second command with a `|` character. Also, when a batch command is successful, the value of `%errorlevel%` is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ("%file%") do Echo Contains Space
```

Which will only `Echo Contains Space` if there is a whitespace in `file`

Comment: Thank you! I was having so much trouble making it work, and was almost about to give up on it, and just let users figure out for them selves that they couldn't use spaces correctly. I'll credit you for your assistance.